# Gitlab runner on kubernetes with tls: handshake failure

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have bare-metal kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes. Also I installed `helm`.
And then I tried to set up gitlab runner using helm according to [guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html), set `runnerToken`, `gitlabUrl`. And ran it.
But pod has not been run. And in the logs of pod I can see following:

```
Registration attempt 30 of 30
Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux pid=333 revision=8ec04662 version=16.3.0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.
WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing:
WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...

Merging configuration from template file "/configmaps/config.template.toml"
ERROR: Verifying runner... failed runner=<runner>
status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/verify:
Post "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/verify": remote error: tls: handshake failure
PANIC: Failed to verify the runner.
```

What is reason this behavior?

UPD:
I got deep and realized that it had not been related to giltab runner. I cannot request `curl -v https://gitlab.com` from any pod in my cluster. Log is below:

```
root@k8s-pod:/# curl -v https://gitlab.com
*   Trying 13.33.243.53:443...
* Connected to gitlab.com (13.33.243.53) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* OpenSSL/3.0.9: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.9: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: How did you set the Helm values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it caused by [known issue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues) and not related to gitab in my case

Comment: So what action did you take to solve the issue? I have a similar problem with TLS errors for the first 10 minutes a node is up, but then it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

The error you presented “sslv3 alert handshake failure” could be caused by several factors. Consider troubleshooting OpenSSL by running this command:

*openssl s_client -connect [gitlab.com:443](http://gitlab.com:443) -servername [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com)*

The information of the handshake will be a great lead on what is causing the error. Also, consider checking the Certificates as there might be compatibility issues as well. Check the version of your OpenSSL just to be sure it's not outdated. Attached are some documentations that may help you on your use case. [1][2]

[1] https://www.openssl.org/docs/

[2] https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/index.html